# ¿Solicitar únicamente camara, no la galería Android?

Tags: java, android, html5, webview

tengo el siguiente código en JAVA Android, es un webview, me gustaría saber por qué al momento de dar clic en el boton type="file" se abre primero la galería de imágenes y luego si me pide los permisos, me gustaría únicamente traer la función de la camara y no las imágenes de la galería.

Este es el archivo MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){

            get_file(); //funcion llama la solicitud de permisos

            if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                if (asw_file_path != null) {
                    asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                }

                asw_file_path = filePathCallback;
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
                Intent[] intentArray;

                if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD) {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = create_image();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", asw_cam_message);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                        }

                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            asw_cam_message = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        } else {
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }
                    if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser");
                //chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, asw_file_req);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Esto claro, fue desarrollado por Ghazi Khan (http://mgks.infeeds.com), Agradeszco cualquier ayuda, gracias de ante mano.